# Suppressing scientific notation when applying operators to very long decimal numbers using the standard library Decimal

Tags: python, decimal

**Using the standard library 'decimal', given two strings:**

```
import decimal
value1 = "992389829398023985092982398023923023.32598203985902"
value2 = "138582939807398509298239235233.3259822352359235203952093"
```

Seperatly the strings can be evaluated and decimals are preserved:

```
>>>> decimal.Decimal(value1)
Decimal("992389829398023985092982398023923023.32598203985902")
>>>> decimal.Decimal(value2)
Decima2("138582939807398509298239235233.3259822352359235203952093")
```

After applying an operator the result is converted to scientific notation, and precision is lost:

```
>>>> decimal.Decimal(value1) - decimal.Decimal(value2)
Decimal('9.923896908150841776944730998E+35')
```

Formatting decimal precision doesnt preserve decimal values:

```
>>>> print("%.40f" % (decimal.Decimal(value1)-decimal.Decimal(value2)))
992389690815084186020235597584531456.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

How can I perform operations to very large decimals, while preserving the integrity of decimal precision, and also supress scientific notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the precision using a [context](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.localcontext):

```
import decimal
from decimal import localcontext
value1 = "992389829398023985092982398023923023.32598203985902"
value2 = "138582939807398509298239235233.3259822352359235203952093"


with localcontext() as ctx:
    #your desired precision in # of digits
    ctx.prec = 100
    print("{:.40f}".format(decimal.Decimal(value1) - decimal.Decimal(value2)))
```

or simply set global value:

```
decimal.getcontext().prec = 100
print("{:.40f}".format(decimal.Decimal(value1) - decimal.Decimal(value2)))
```

output:

```
992389690815084177694473099784687789.9999998046230964796047907000000000000000
```

or by printing the statement (ie. `decimal.Decimal(value1) - decimal.Decimal(value2)`):

```
Decimal('992389690815084177694473099784687789.9999998046230964796047907')
```